# Overflow and fill out of the parent frame

Tags: html, css

The .modal_content fill out of parent and '.inner' also (here are 20 values putted in the table rows). When I add `height: 10em;` to '.inner' style then it works, but with percentage of the parent's height it don't works. I would like to put in the modal window a table and a buttons at the bottom of this modal window.

My code:

```js
var cnt = $(".modal_content").empty();

$("<i>", {text:"Pin states", class:''}).appendTo(cnt);

var div = $("<div>", {class:"inner"}).appendTo(cnt);
var tbl = $("<table>", id="m_Pins").appendTo(div);
var ii = 0;

p_state.forEach(function(d){
  var tr = $("<tr>", {class:"m_pin_set"}).data({"num":ii}).appendTo(tbl);
  
  $("<td>", {text:ii+"."}).appendTo(tr);
  $("<td>", {text:d}).appendTo(tr);
  ii++;
});

$(".modal").show();
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.6);
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

.modal_form {
  z-index: 3;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 210, 1);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal_content {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 1em auto 1em auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 80%;
}

.modal_content table {}

.m_btn {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal_form">
    <div class="modal_content">
      <i>Header</i>
      <div class='inner'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_btns">
      <button class="m_btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could somebody explain what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What is `p_state `?

Comment: Please just give us the css regarding the issue, your snippet is not running (and also contains a lot of this that are not part of the issue)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uhqfbm1L/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HPcHHqxog3GBZ-Jvt4Qrkqv3Mk0v43Hu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want that ".inner" should be flex (height) and resized automaticaly between first tag <i> and button that places at the bottom. At this moment the size of ".inner" are full size and overflow parent. I can set "height: 10em" - it fiex problem, but it not scalable.

Comment: I have solved - add  "height: calc(100% - 3em);" to ". modal_content" and clean up styles that not reflect on the result